# tool in terminal like helm-occur/helm-swoop for terminal?

Tags: command-line, grep, search, interactive

I don't know whether this is the right place to post this question, but if you are not an Emacs user, I'll explain the basic usage of helm-occur/helm-swoop.

I like helm-occur/helm-swoop for Emacs very much, but when I'm not using Emacs, is there any tool in terminal for me that acts like helm-occur/helm-swoop, it does not need to provide all features that they provide, all I need is to search pattern in directories/files, and it will list all the matches and I can choose one of them and jump to it for viewing or editing, after viewing or editing, I can go back to the list and choose another, there is a package called [percol](https://github.com/mooz/percol) that will list the matches, but It cannot jump to the file.

BTW, I use ag or grep.

Comment: Why not use `emacsclient -nw`?

Comment: @Gilles I mean a tool in terminal completely outside of Emacs

Answer (score 0):

Try [PathPicker](https://github.com/facebook/PathPicker).

> PathPicker is a simple command line tool that solves the perpetual problem of selecting files out of bash output.

[Installation](https://github.com/facebook/PathPicker#installing-pathpicker)

From [examples](https://github.com/facebook/PathPicker#examples):

```
git status | fpp
grep -r "FooBar" . | fpp
find . -iname "*.js" | fpp
```

Use the `-ko` option if you want go back to the list:

> -ko, --keep-open      keep PathPicker open once a file selection or command is performed. This will loop the program until Ctrl-C is used to terminate the process.

Note about editor:

> The $FPP_EDITOR environment variable can be set to tell PathPicker
>   which editor to open the selected files with. If that variable
>   is not set, $VISUAL and then $EDITOR are used as fallbacks,
>   with "vim" as a last resort.

**Update**:
There is an undocumented feature in `fpp`: `fpp` [recognizes](https://github.com/facebook/PathPicker/blob/master/src/output.py#L95) the line numbers in `grep` output. So, you can add a line number `grep -rn foo . | fpp -ko` and jump to the matched lines.

Comment: "PathPicker is a combination of a bash script and some small Python modules.". It seems it doesn't support fishshell.